# Create a div with triangle cut on the left side middle

Tags: html, css

I want to design a div which look like :

[image]

I tried to find out on the web but i could not able to find this kind of design.

Dotted line is not required as it came there white taking the screenshot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.sample{
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
}

.sample::after{
  width: 0;
height: 0;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 25px 0 25px 50px;
border-color: transparent transparent transparent #FFF;
display: block;
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sample"> </div>
```

```
.sample{
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
}

.sample::after{
  width: 0;
height: 0;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 25px 0 25px 50px;
border-color: transparent transparent transparent #FFF;
display: block;
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: when i am applying the .sample propert (i.e: height and width in %) the container is not displaying

Comment: If you want to give % `height` and `width` to the `div`, then give that `height` and `width` to the `html` and `body`

Comment: In order for a percentage value to work for height, the parent's height must be determined

Comment: check this link http://cssreference.io or if you want to watch you can check this channel https://www.youtube.com/DevTipsForDesigners

Answer (score 0):

This can help you which you want to achieve.

```css
.sample {
    height: 200px;
    width: 160px;
    background: #fff;
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid #000;
}

.sample::after {
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #000;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 20px 0 20px 30px;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    width: 0;
}

.sample::before {
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #fff;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 19px 0 19px 28px;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    left: -2px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 31px;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 1;
```

```html
<div class="sample"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try following code

```css
.sample{
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
  border:2px solid #000;
}

.sample::after{
  width: 11px;
  height: 11px;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 2px;
border-color: #000 #000 #fff #FFF;
display: block;
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
 left:-10px;
-ms-transform: rotate(45deg); 
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); 
transform: rotate(45deg);
background-color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="sample"></div>
```